# Count frequency of values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, bioinformatics, rosalind

Having this pandas.core.frame.DataFrame:

```
Gorilla     A  T  C  C  A  G  C  T
Dog         G  G  G  C  A  A  C  T
Humano      A  T  G  G  A  T  C  T
Drosophila  A  A  G  C  A  A  C  C
Elefante    T  T  G  G  A  A  C  T
Mono        A  T  G  C  C  A  T  T
Unicornio   A  T  G  G  C  A  C  T
```

I would like to get a data frame like that:

```
    A   5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0
    C   0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1
    G   1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
    T   1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
```

Basically, what I want is to count the frequent column by column and create the second df as I show.

I want to do this because finally, I would like to get a Consensus string. Should be something like that    A T G C A A C T

Could anyone help me or give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
result = df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
A   5.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   5.0   5.0   0.0   0.0
C   0.0   0.0   1.0   4.0   2.0   0.0   6.0   1.0
G   1.0   1.0   6.0   3.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
T   1.0   5.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0   6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) by column:

```
print(df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0))
```

**Output**

```
     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
A  5.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  5.0  5.0  0.0  0.0
C  0.0  0.0  1.0  4.0  2.0  0.0  6.0  1.0
G  1.0  1.0  6.0  3.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
T  1.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  6.0
```